# Submultiplicity of matrix norm from the spectral radius $ + \epsilon$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms, spectral-radius

I found this statement (e.g., from here [Matrix norm and spectral radius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834062/matrix-norm-and-spectral-radius))

> For every $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a matrix norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ such that $\Vert A \Vert < \rho(A) + \epsilon$ where $\rho(A)$ is the spectral radius of $A$, i.e., the magnitude of its largest eigenvalue.

I don't need to prove this statement, but I'm having difficulty to see how to prove this and I can't find this in a reference. **The important question I want to answer is if all such matrix norms are submultiplicative**, i.e., $\Vert A B \Vert \leq \Vert A \Vert \Vert B \Vert$. Ultimately I need to show that $\sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} (A^t)^T Q A^t$ is *well defined*, where $Q$ is some fixed symmetric positive definite matrix. So it would be very easy if I can argue that all the matrix norms from this statement are submultiplicative.

Comment: Here is a proof that there **is** a suitable submultiplicative norm https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3994855/27978. However, this does not prove that all norms that satisfy the requirements are submultiplicative .

Comment: @user The norm used in the post that you linked is indeed submultiplicative

Comment: @BenGrossmann Oh true, since it's an induced norm...